# IE7 javascript error: runtime-error microsoft jscript: dropdownlist is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have another error caused by IE7 (great program...) I am trying to get a dropdownlist into a javascript function so that i can use it's values to hid some divs which are named after those values. but each time I try to use this dropdownlist I get the following error:
runtime-error microsoft jscript: dropdownlist is not defined

the javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/ShowHide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

function ShowHideDivByDropDownList(dropdownlist) {
  for (i = 0; i < dropdownlist.options.lenght; i++) {
      var divId = dropdownlist.options[i].value;
      if (divId != "") {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  document.getElementById(drowdownlist.value).style.display = "block";
}
```

the dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MainList",
                    new SelectList(Model.ListCategories, 
                    Model.List,
                    new { onchange ="ShowHideDivByDropDownList(this)"})
```

EDIT:

I have made allot of trail adjustments to try and make the script running, allot of people seem to have noticed this :). I have returned to script to it's original state, but the error still occurs.

Comment: The error is not specific for IE7, removed the tag. It would happen in any browser even the great Chrome. I recommend to check such things on more browsers before deciding it's specific to one of them. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It does only occur on IE7, I use Chrome and it works perfectly fine there, also on IE9, It only occurs when i turn on compatibility mode on IE9 to simulate IE7.

Comment: If you change the code to `onchange ="alert(this); ShowHideDivByDropDownList(this)"` what do you see in the alert when changing value?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get an Alert with "[object]" as content.

Comment: So it's impossible that you get "dropdownlist is not defined" error. You missed something else.

Comment: I have found what caused the error, IE somehow saved an old version of dropdownlist in it's cache where the name was different, this caused this weird error. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an ID use `getElementById(id)`, if it's a name use `getElementsByName(name)[0]`.

`getElementByName` doesn't exist.

Also be careful with your variable names...

Answer (score 0):

In your **for** loop you have **drowdownlish** instead of **drowdownlist**. Just for sanity sake you may want to make those **dropdownlist**.

```
function ShowHideDivByDropDownList(dropdownlistid) {
  var dropdownlist= document.getElementByName(dropdownlistid);
  for (i = 0; i < dropdownlist.options.count; i++) {
      var divId = dropdownlist.options[i].value;
      if (divId != "") {
          document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  document.getElementById(dropdownlist.value).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: oh yes sorry about that, missed that one when I adjusted the naming :P but it isn't what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent yourself all this mess - as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263206/447356) correctly said, you have to use `getElementById` but if you change your code to this:

```
onchange ="ShowHideDivByDropDownList(this)"
```

Then you pass the actual object to the function then you can safely have such code instead:

```
function ShowHideDivByDropDownList(drowdownlist) {
    for (var i = 0; i < drowdownlist.options.length; i++) {
        var divId = drowdownlist.options[i].value;
        if (divId !== "") {
            var element = document.getElementById(divId);
            if (element)
                element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    var element = document.getElementById(drowdownlist.value);
    if (element)
        element.style.display = "block";
}
```

Couple of things I fixed along the way as well:

1. In JavaScript, array length is `.length`, not `.count`
2. In case there's no element with such ID your code would crash - to avoid such mishap it's always good practice to validate you really have such element - you can add `alert("element does not exist");` for debug purpose but having the whole code crash because you have typo is not a good thing.